# Seneca.js, Promises, and Error Handling

Tags: node.js, promise, seneca

We are using [seneca.js](http://senecajs.org/) to put messages into a queue in our Node app. We promisified the `act` call, and wrapped all the seneca use in a service we called MessageBus. So now, MessageBus.publish uses Seneca to put the call on a queue and wait for a response:

```
MessageBus.publish({ ... })
    .then(result => doSomething(result))
    .catch(error => handleError(error));
```

Here's the relevant part of the service that we wrote:

```
function MessageBus() {
    //initialization
    seneca.use('seneca-amqp-transport'); //instruct seneca to use a transport

    seneca.client({});
    seneca.listen({});

    const act = function(message, cb) {
        seneca.act(message, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                cb(err);
            } else {
                cb(null, response);
            }
        });
    };

    const promisified = Promise.promisify(act, { context: seneca });

    return {
        publish: promisified,
    };
}

module.exports = MessageBus();
```

On every call, we needed to add the `catch` to handle errors. That worked pretty well, but had a lot of repeated code.

Now, we're using `async/await`, and I'd like to handle the errors all in one spot and not need to wrap every call in a `try/catch` block. My attempts, though, didn't work.

What I added was a function that called the `promisified` function and caught the errors. Then `publish` exported that function instead. It half worked, but in the `act` function, `cb` was not defined. No matter what I tried, `cb` was never defined and never called.

I know it looks like errors are handled in the `seneca.act`, but the express app will still crash if an error occurs and the `MessageBus.publish` isn't wrapped in a `try/catch` block.

My goal was to have something along the lines of [Wes Bos's solution in this `catchErrors` function](https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Node/blob/master/starter-files/handlers/errorHandlers.js#L9). I'd love to not have to wrap every `MessageBus.publish` call in a `try/catch` block, but instead write that code in one spot and have all the errors handled there.

Comment: The thing about try/catch is that exceptions propagate upwards anyway - so you can just handle them at a higher level of your program.

Comment: Could you add the express route handler as well so we can get a better overview of what you're trying to do? We're all programmers here, so code usually explains better than words. One thing I've noticed is the `const act = ...` function isn't required, you could just do `Promise.promisify(seneca.act, { context: seneca })`. Also, what's the actual error your program crashes with?

Comment: The app is a Sails.js app, which is built on express. And if I don't catch the errors, then it's actually Seneca that crashes and requires the app to be restarted. And I know the above code could be changed to be promisified like you mentioned, but we actually do a little bit of other stuff in that act function that I didn't put in because it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: If there was no *other stuff* in that act function, then you could write `'publish': Promise.promisify(seneca.act, { 'context': seneca }),`. In composing an answer taking *other stuff* into account, one would need to know whether that stuff was to be executed synchronously (before calling `senena.act()`) or asynchronously after `senena.act()` responds - (or a bit of each).

Comment: Either way, you shouldn't be promisifying your own `act()` function. That misnderstanding is what's giving you an issue with `cb`.